# Step Function nested Map step in Map step

Tags: amazon-web-services, nested, aws-step-functions

I have been working on step functions for a couple of weeks now. I am using map state in my step functions to iterate over an array. The array has an additional inner array as well, thus I would like to employ an addition map step in the "outer" map state. [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) does not go into this level of details (as of now), therefore, I wanted to share that I managed to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to nest map steps:

```
"OuterMapState": {
    "Type": "Map",
    "ItemsPath": "$.shipped",
    "MaxConcurrency": 0,
    "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "Validate",
        "States": {
            "Validate": {
                "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:ship-val",
                "Next": "InnerMapState"
            },
            "InnerMapState": {
                "Type": "Map",
                "ItemsPath": "$.shipped.innerArray",
                "MaxConcurrency": 0,
                "Iterator": {
                    "StartAt": "doSomething",
                    "States": {
                        "doSomething": {
                            "Type": "Pass",
                            "End": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "End": true
        }
    },
    "End": true
}
```

Good luck on using AWS Step functions.